# C# htmlagilitypack XPath except containt html tag

Tags: xpath, html-agility-pack

```
<div id="Dossuuu11Plus" style="display: block; ">
Text need
<br/>
  Not need
  <a class="bot_link" href="http://abc.com" target="_self">http://abc.com</a>
  <br/>
</div>
```

This is html code. I use: //td[@class='textdetaildrgI
but it get all content in , I just need "Text need". Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
//div[@id='Dossuuu11Plus']/text()[1][normalize-space()]
```

**Explanation:** 
It will select the first text node found for `DIV` which in this case is `Text need` and `normalize-space()` will trim leading and trailing whitespaces if any.

Comment: If you find it useful and working then you can upvote and accept the answer :)